# Why didn't I get the Java bronze tag badge?

Tags: support, tag-badges

According to the Help Center, the requirement of earning the Java bronze tag badge is:

> Earned at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the java tag.

I've answered many questions with the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag and gained more than 500 reputation, but I haven't gotten the Java bronze tag badge.

Could someone tell me why?  Am I misunderstanding some of the rules?

Comment: You only have a score of 30 in the Java tag. Tag score is just number of upvotes minus number of downvotes on answers in that tag. It has nothing to do with reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a net tag score (upvotes minus downvotes) of 100, along with at least 20 non-wiki answers associated with that tag.  Your [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag score is only 30, *but* you have provided enough answers.  You must fulfill both of those criteria.

Answer (score 3):

Score = votes on answers, not reputation.